Remove Route annotation from an action in ASP.NET Core 8
In my ASP.NET Core 8 project, I added a reference to a nuget package containing the following controller:
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{
    // ...

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("cart")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string shoppingCartId = null)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

How can I dynamically remove the data annotation [Route("cart")] from the Index action?
I would like remove this action with a code written inside the Startup.cs of my ASP.NET Core 8 project, so I can remap this action using route.MapAreaControllerRoute() inside Startup.cs.
Maybe I should remove it by using reflection?

Could you please describe your issue more clearly ? If you are attempting to reaching another action with the same url cart?id=**, based on my research it is not feasible. If you want to ignore the route attribute which is to reach the action through controller/index, customize the constraint in startup.cs , catch the cart and retype with  index.

I want Index() action must not be reacheable with the link /cart, but with my custom link.

This issue is about combining conventional routing and attribute routing. There is no sample about overriding attribute with routing configuration in program and in my test it won't work. You could disable the /cart link with custom mapget app.MapGet("/cart", async context => {     context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound; }); But cannot redefine a new endpoint. What's more , MapAreaControllerRoute will require area attribute in controller, which needs modification on the attribute, so it is not feasible.
